# Detecting The Page & Then Doing Something

Tags: php

I need the "Pages" link to be able to detect if the user is on any of the pages that are included in the dropdown menu for "Pages". Detecting whether they are on only 1 page is easy, I need to add multiple instances to the "Pages" item. Hopefully that makes a little more sense.

Here is what I have:

```
<li class='dropdown' id="menu1">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu1">Pages</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="about.php">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

A example of what the code would look like for JUST index.php would be:

```
<li <?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'index.php') !== false) {echo 'class="active"';} ?>>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
</li>
```

Like I said before, I need to add multiple instances in basically one PHP block to detect MORE THAN if the user is JUST ON *[filename]*.php

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Please give us an update if you found out how to detect the weather using PHP.

Comment: What do you mean? In my thread there is an example showing how to do it with PHP. My question is just how to detect multiple pages

Comment: oh HAHA, well do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to extract just the page name, then you need to compare it to the array of posible pages:

```
<?php if (in_array(preg_replace('|.*/(.+\.php).*|i','\\1',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), array('index.php','about.php'))) {echo 'class="active"';}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put your list items in an array. And then loop over them to create the menu.

```
$pages = array(
    'Home' => 'home.php',
    'About' => 'about.php'
);

<?php foreach ($pages as $name => $url): ?>
    <li <?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $url) !== false):
        echo 'class="active"';
    endif ?>>
        <a href="<?php echo $url?>"><?php echo $name?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This will check each result in the array to see if it matches the uri. If it does it will add the active class to the li.